# Bachelor Thesis: ML Soccer prediction - what model?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I am starting with ML and am kinda lost.

My Bachelor Thesis revolves around the prediction of soccer games and my mentor thought it would be fun to do that with ML - interesting yes, fun not so much.

I am using the [API-FOOTBALL (from Rapid-Api)](https://rapidapi.com/) to get data on players from matches. I am currently restricted on the testdata and will work only with one league.

The Data from one match looks something like this:

```
eventID plyrID  name            pos rating      minPlayed  capatin  goals shots   ...
169080  2429    Edison Flores   F   7,600000    72         False    0     0       ...
169080  2455    Fernando Ari.   F   7,200000    90         False    1     2       ...
169080  2482    Camilo Vargas   G   8,700000    90         False    0     3       ...
169080  2556    Sebastian Vegas D   7,700000    90         False    0     0       ...
169080  2570    Gabriel Achi.   D   6,300000    90         False    0     0       ...
169080  35661   Joaquín Martí.  D   6,900000    90         False    0     1       ...
...     ...     ...
```

Overall somewhat 40 rows with individual **parameters**.

I want to get a score for team **a** =∑ { x1,…,xn } where **x** is a player and the sum of each **parameter * k** where **k** is the unknown weight of each parameter. Same with team **b**.

I think my intention is to use ML to get the weight for each parameter but I am lost on how to implement that. My premise is that each weight is somewhat of a constant and can be used to calculate a score for each game.

How can I do that? What Model/approach do I need for that?

Comment: You have a supervised learning problem. What are your predictors and your response variable of interest? Start by identifying those.

Comment: [You could start by going through this list of similar Qs with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=soccer+predic*++answers%3A1)

Comment: If you consider *weights* to mean *coefficients* and for *parameter* to mean *independent variable* in your data, you could always start with some form of regularized regression i.e. LASSO, ridge, or elastic-net etc.